# setting PATH in windows using python

Tags: python, path, environment-variables

Hi I am trying to check for java version by using below python code

```
os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"] + os.pathsep + "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin"
os.system("java -version")
```

but it shows this error message

'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17176423/198633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\b'` is a BACKSPACE character, not `\` and `b`.

```
>>> "\b"
'\x08'
>>> print("\b")
```

To represent `\` and `b` literally, you need to escape `\`, or use `r'raw string literal'`:

```
>>> print("\\b")
\b
>>> print(r"\b")
\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to print the PATH

```
os.system("echo %PATH%")
```

then I found some weird text like below

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20in
```

\b in \bin is showing as backspace char in path

replace path with below works fine

```
C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_20\\bin
```